# Automated test using java.util

Tags: java

I want to write a automated test using java.util for a website. I am not too clear on how random() is used but...

1. I want to create a new account for the website, upon creating the account I want the username and password to be made from taking random letters from the alphabet.
2. After creating the password it should confirm the random password that was made.
3. Log in the website using the credentials that were made.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void createNewAccount() {

    clickOnCss("#not_logged_user");
    typeInCss("#quicksignup_name", "randomName");
    typeInCss("#quicksignup_email", "myEmail");
    typeInCss("#quicksignup_pass", "randomPassword");
    typeInCss("#quicksignup_pass_confirm", "confirmRandomPassword");
    clickOnCss("#quicksignup_button");

}

public void SignInWithNewAccount(){
    clickOnCss("hp_login_bt");
    typeInCss("#quicklogin_name", "NewRandomName");
    typeInCss("#quicklogin_pass", "NewRandomPassword");

}

@Test
public void randomName() {
Random signUp = new Random();
int name = signUp.nextInt(26) + (byte) 'a';

}
```

Comment: You appear to be using a library to automate your web testing, what is it?

Comment: Also, what is your question?

Comment: Your question is not clear? Are you asking help about using random(), then why all this bloat.

Comment: Use Scrapy with Requests in python instead of java selenium. That's gonna save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Change this one to:

```
public void createNewAccount(String name) {
    clickOnCss("#not_logged_user");
    typeInCss("#quicksignup_name", name);
    typeInCss("#quicksignup_email", "myEmail");
    typeInCss("#quicksignup_pass", "randomPassword");
    typeInCss("#quicksignup_pass_confirm", "confirmRandomPassword");
    clickOnCss("#quicksignup_button");
}

@Test
public void randomName() {
    Random signUp = new Random();
    String name = signUp.nextInt(26).toString() + 'a';
    createNewAccount(name);
}
```

Something like that, add more parameters if you need them.